# is it possible to add new methods to a inherited module in openerp

Tags: inheritance, odoo, openerp-7

I have a inherited module for "purchase".
If I add a new method in purchase.py, I am able to use it in my view (form). However if i add it in inherited module. I am not able to use it in form view.

Is there a way to add my new method in inherited module?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible you can add new methods in inherited module,paste ur code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you have to do for your code to work in inherited module is use:

```
_inherit = 'purchase.order'
```

And then call your function from the updated xml view. For example check code like that:

```
class account_asset_asset(osv.osv):

    _inherit = 'account.asset.asset'

    def _check_value(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        for asset in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            if asset.purchase_value < 0.0:
                return False
        return True

    _constraints = [
        (_check_value, 'Asset value must be greater than 0!', ['purchase_value']),
    ]
```

That will check if the purchase_value of an asset is greater than 0 and return False if not, so that user will not be able to save his record. What is more, you can easily override the function used in inherited model so that it works the way you want it to work.